# Laravel 5: second app is pointing to first app, how can I fix this?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

*Changed the application folder names in question to `application1/application2` just for the purposes of this question.*

If it makes any difference, I am using Homestead/Vagrant/VirtualBox.

**In my homestead.yaml, I have this:**

```
folders:
    - map: ~/Homestead/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Sites
sites:
    - map: application1.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Sites/application1/public
    - map: application2.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Sites/application2/public
```

**In my hosts file, I have this:**

```
127.0.0.1 application1.app application2.app
192.168.10.10 application1.app application2.app
```

When I just had the application1.app on both the homestead.yaml and hosts file, all was fine and dandy. Everything is still fine and dandy, however when I try to go to application2.app, it goes to the project in application1.app.

- I tried flushing my DNS cache, no luck.
- I tried `vagrant --provision`, no luck.

Can anyone please explain to me what I'm, doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For anyone with this problem**

Solved this with `vagrant provision`. My other method of `vagrant --provision` didn't work because there is no provision flag (according to freenode #laravel irc), so that must be for an older version - not Laravel 5.